# Como puedo hacer que una función este constantemente activa? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, entrada

Hola de tarea me dejaron hacer un programa que capture datos y pues tengo que limitar las entradas para que solo acepten cierto tipo de datos y un máximo de ellos , estoy utilizando tkinter la solución que se me ocurrió fue crear esta función

```
    def comprobar (self):
        if len(self.numero1) > 10:
            self.entrada_5.delete(10,'end')
```

Pero no se como hacer que funcione sin la necesidad de un botón , probé con un while pero con este no me iniciaba la ventana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explicación

Puedes usar dos argumentos especiales para hacer que una función valide el contenido de un entry:

- validate: Que tipo de validación hay que hacer. Nosotros usaremos 'key' que es especificamente para validar lo que escribe el usuario.
- validatecommand: Acepta una tupla. El primer item de la tupla debe ser una función registrada con `widget.register`. Esta función debe devolver True o False (nota: si no devuelve esto, va a anularse la validación).
  Si la función devuelve True, el entry va a cambiar. Si devuelve False, la acción hecha por el usuario no tendrá efecto.
  El resto de los items de la tupla son los tipos de argumentos a pasar. Por ejemplo si pasamos a validatecommand esta tupla: `(widget.register(func), "%P", "%s")` cuando la función sea llamada será como `func(nuevo texto, viejo texto)`

#### Código

A continuación, agregaré un código de ejemplo que hace algo similar a lo que buscas:

```
import tkinter as tk

def validator(nuevo_texto):
    if(len(nuevo_texto) > 10):
        return False
    else:
        return True

v = tk.Tk()

entrada = tk.Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=(v.register(validator), "%P"))
entrada.pack()

v.mainloop()
```

O su equivalente un poco menos entendible:

```
import tkinter as tk

def validator(nuevo_texto):
    return (len(nuevo_texto) <= 10)

v = tk.Tk()

entrada = tk.Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=(v.register(validator), "%P"))
entrada.pack()

v.mainloop()
```

O usando una función lambda:

```
import tkinter as tk

entrada = tk.Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=(v.register(lambda nuevo_texto:(len(nuevo_texto) <= 10)), "%P"))
entrada.pack()

v.mainloop()
```

#### Bonus

Por cierto, puedes usar [el modulo re](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html) para validar los entrys con expresiones regulares. Por ejemplo una regex para validar un decimal positivo que me gusta sería `r"\d*(\.\d*)?"`.
Podemos usar [fullmatch](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) para validar que toda la cadena coincida con la regex.  fullmatch devuelve un [objeto match](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#match-objects) si la cadena coincide y si no devuelve None. Por lo que podemos agregar `is not None` para que devuelva False si lo devuelto es el objeto None y de lo contrario True.

```
entrada = tk.Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=(v.register(lambda nuevo_texto:(re.fullmatch(r"\d*(\.\d*)?", nuevo_texto) is not None)), "%P"))
```

#### Más información

Puedes aprender más sobre las validaciones de los entrys en estas paginas:

- https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/validar-el-contenido-de-una-caja-de-texto-en-tkinter/
- https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

tienes que manejar eso con eventos. Por ejemplo, cada vez que se apreta una tecla, corres tu función:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def onKeyPress(event):
    # tu funcion aqui..
    text.insert('end', 'You pressed %s\n' % (event.char, ))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
text = tk.Text(root, background='black', foreground='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', 12))
text.pack()
root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
root.mainloop()
```